# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Order[]'

Tags: angular, rxjs

Getting this strange error in my HTML that says property 'id' does not exist on type Order[] when it does very explicitly exists

The error: `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Order[]'`

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="admin-page" *ngIf="order">
  <p-card [header]="'View Order'" subheader="You can edit order status here">
          <h5>Order Id</h5>
          <p>{{ order.id }}</p> //HERE I AM GETTING THE ERROR
        </div>
```

Here is the relevant ts:

```
export class OrderDetailComponent {
  order: Order[] = [];

private _getOrder() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      if (params['id']) {
        this.orderService
          .getOrder(params['id'])
          .subscribe((order) => {
            this.order = order;
            console.log(this.order);
          });
      }
    });
  }

}
```

And the orde.ts file:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import { User } from '@eshop-repository/users';
import { OrderItem } from './order-item';

export class Order {
  
  id?: string;
  orderItems?: OrderItem[];
  shippingAddress1?: string;
  shippingAddress2?: string;
  city?: string;
  zip?: string;
  country?: string;
  phone?: string;
  status?: number;
  totalPrice?: string;
  user?: User;
  dateOrdered?: string;
  _id?: string;
  
}
```

And the order-item.ts file:

```
/* eslint-disable @nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries */
import { Product } from "@eshop-repository/products";

export class OrderItem {
    product?: Product;
    quantity?: number;
  }
```

The error I am getting is that id doesn't exist on Order, when you can see it very clearly does. Order is an array, maybe that is causing the problems?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `order` as an array of Order (`Order[]`)

Simply change your declaration to

```
export class OrderDetailComponent {
  order: Order; //instead of Order[]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent. But when I do that, then I get an error: Type `'Order[]' has no properties in common with type 'Order'.` in the line ` this.order = order;`

Comment: then in your orderService your getOrder() method also returns a `Observable<getOrder[]>` instead of `Observable<getOrder>`

Comment: Thanks Laurent, you were spot on, however now I am getting a different error when I do all of this: https://paste.pics/83ef81e81618ba7ac8f3a1c2f68704aa it says "Object is possibly 'undefined', I have tried the '?' method, error goes away but data is not fetched

Comment: you can add a ? operator in your template so that it will return undefined instead of throwing an exception, then it will compile.
eg:
`orderItem.product?.name`

Comment: i didn't see you already did, but data isn't fetched... the ? has nothing to do with the data being fetched or not, check the code that fetches your data